# Calculate e^x given epsilon and x values in c

Tags: c, function, exponent, epsilon

```
long double power1(double x, int n) {
    long double power = 1;
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        power *= i;
    }
    return power;
}

long long int factorial(long long n) {
    long long int pr = 1;
    long long int i;
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++){
        pr *= i;
    }
    return pr;
}

double myExp(double x, double epsi) {
    double sum=(double)1;
    int i;

    while(power1(x, i)/((1.0)*factorial(i)) - epsi <= 0) {
        sum += power1(x, i)/(1.0*factorial(i));
        i++;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    system("cls");
    double x, epsi;
    int n;

    x=1.5;
    epsi=0.00001;
    n=1000;

    printf("exp(%.lf,%f)=%f\n", x, epsi, myExp(x, epsi));
    printf("\n");
}
```

I need help to fix my exponential function `e^x` given the `epsi` value and `x` value such that `abs(x^n/n!) <= epsi`, where `n` is the first integer satisfying the condition. It seems the while loop doesn't work. When I enter `1.5`, the desired output is `4.481689`, but the result is `1.0000`.

Comment: `power1(x,i)/((1.0)*factorial(i))-epsi<=0` does not involve the absolute value.

Comment: Change `power*=i;` to `power*=x;`  in `power1`.  You aren't even using `x` in `power1` as it is now.  If you enable compiler warnings, it will immediately point of bugs like that.

Comment: didn't expect this mistake,thanks!

Comment: @chux-Reinstate-Monica Do you have alternative way to write condition in the while loop?

Comment: `power1` and `factorial` are doing the same calculation but with different types.

Comment: You don't seem to initialise `i` in `myExp`.  Also, each time round the loop you calculate `power1()` and `factorial()` twice, *and* for each `i` you repeat the calculation for `i-1`.